# Value difference when converting from double(float64) to float(float32) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

When I run the simple code:

```
a = np.float64([20269207])
b = np.float32(a)
```

The output turns to be

```
a = array([20269207.])
b = array([20269208.], dtype=float32)
```

What reason causes the difference before and after this conversion? And in what condition the outputs will be different?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to store the value `20269207` in the `float32` ([IEEE 754](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4610935)) format.

You may see, why:

It is possible to store the values `20269206` and `20269208`; their representations in binary form are (see [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)):

- `01001011100110101010010001001011` for `20269206`
- `01001011100110101010010001001100` for `20269208`

Their binary forms differ by `1`, so *there is no place for any number between `20269206` and `20269208`*.

By the rounding rules **“Round to nearest, ties to even”** and **“Round to nearest, ties away from zero”** of [IEEE 754](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4610935), your number is rounded to the nearest **even higher** number, i.e. to the number `20269208`.

---

Outputs for integer numbers will be different:

- for odd numbers with absolute value greater than `16,777,216`,
- for **almost all** numbers with absolute value greater than `33,554,432`.

Notes:

1. The first number is `2^24`, the second one is `2^25`.
2. "allmost all" - there are "nice" numbers, such as powers of 2, which have precise representations even for **very very large numbers**.

Comment: "Outputs for integer numbers will be different ... for all numbers with absolute value greater than 33,554,432" - what? No. float32 can still represent plenty of numbers that float64 can at that point, particularly any multiple of 4. As you go higher, numbers have to be "evener" to be representable, up until you hit the maximum exponent.

Comment: Any multiple of 4 up to the next power-of-2 threshold, at which point you need multiples of 8, then 16, and so on. 80000004 is past the multiples-of-8 threshold.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/bIACaw) showing that float32 can exactly represent 80000008, which is a multiple of 8, but definitely not a power of 2.